# Android WebView shows a blank page

Tags: android, webview

Trying to create a WebView but it only shows a blank/white page. I have followed several examples and they all say that work with this code...

**Here is my code:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class PostenWebView extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.web_view);
        WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

**And here is the web_view.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am having this problem too.  My code:
  mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
  mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  mWebView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
  url="http://www.google.com"; 
  mWebView.loadUrl(url);
Doesn't show the web page until after an orientation change.  Then the page shows up fine.

Comment: Same problem here. Doesn't show the web page until an orientation change or clicking the webview. Then the page shows up fine. Any solution for this!

Comment: It could be that while you want to load www.google.com the actual URL is different(I tried myself www.google.com in the browser and final URL is slightly different). There is a known bug that will not allow a webview to load URL's with parameters. There is also a fix. I could not get it working though. Sorry I can not find the relevant links. I found the problem a while ago.

Answer (score 16):

You need to enable Javascript (`.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)`), or choose a Web page that does not rely upon Javascript.

Comment: i am trying to read header of gmail account using http://stackoverflow.com/a/3134609/336990 , but final htmlContent which i am getting not able to load in web view ..showing me blank screen, if same html data file i run on browser it showing me to choose my mail account for allow acceess...why it showing blank screen in emulator

Comment: The problem doesn't depend on Javascript being enabled

Answer (score 4):

You have to add the permission to your AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Alreade done that... I use internet in several other activities in my application and they are working just fine, so that can't be what's making it show a blank page... :/

Comment: I don't know anything else other than this. Make sure you have 3G icon the taskbar. If you do this in emulator restart it a couple of times to get it there.

Answer (score 3):

Use webview.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); method

Comment: You save my day! Thanks.

Comment: What was the problem and how comes this fixes it?

Comment: Well, what it's doing is changing the way that the renderer renders the page, in this case, use a software renderer (the cpu), why that actually helps anything I have no idea.

Answer (score 3):

It's works fine for me

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
});

webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting redirected..
just install a webviewclient allong with you web view :)

Answer (score 0):

in my case loading google.com worked but my login page returned a completely white page. Adding this fixed it:

```
            WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            String databasePath = webView.getContext().getDir("databases", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath();
            webSettings.setDatabasePath(databasePath);
```

Answer (score -3):

The quick and dirty solution can be when your android app get started set the background colour according to web view eg i am using black colour so 
myWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

Comment: This is not a solution to her problem

Answer (score -4):

if you try to load a HTTPS URL (e.g. Foursquare authentication URL) do not forget to call

`webview.clearSslPreferences();`

before trying to load that

Comment: She is not trying to load an https url. And blindly using `clearSslPreferences` is recipe for disaster

Comment: What if we are loading a https website, is this useful? What problems could it cause?