# Splash screen android phonegap timing

Tags: android, eclipse, callback, splash-screen

I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156841/phonegap-splash-screen-for-android-app) this code:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html",5000);
```

And it works, but like this, result is:

- Splash screen for 5 seconds
- Black screen until the app is ready
- index.html when app is ready

So I was wondering if there is any chance of running this

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

As a callback of some ready function, is there a way?

-EDIT-

Changing it to 10 seconds doesn't show me the black screen but I would like to show index.html the exact same moment that the app is ready (not sooner, not much later :D)

Comment: try with   super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl(), 10000);

Comment: I see, but that way we can't be sure the app is ready, or if it was ready a while a go..

Comment: i means you try to increase delay time 5000 to 10000

Comment: Yes I understand, but i want to show it untill the app is ready, not 10 seconds. As I said, it might be ready allready but i might not yet!

Comment: Have you taken a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587888/how-to-determine-when-android-webview-is-completely-done-loading
It might work if you don't have redirects...

Answer (score 1):

```
        // Show LOGO ，start to  MainActivity that watting for some seconds
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /*
                 * Create an Intent that will start the Main WordPress
                 * Activity.
                 */
                //
                RedirectMainActivity();
            }
        }, 4000);
```

Comment: you know any thing about phone-gap

Comment: what? Could you give me the details!

Answer (score 0):

Android does not provide any of native API to deal with Splash Screen
but you can use `Handler` to show fake splash screen.

```
  //load the splash screen
  super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/someSplashScreen.html");
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
                    // splash screen successfully timeout
                    //start new activity or load html layout
                     super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

        }
    }, 4000);//timeout after 4 sec
```

Comment: Just one question, why the 4 seconds delay? the thing is that i want no extra delay at all, i just want to use the splashcreen as a 'loading' image:), if I put  0 there will that achieve it? thanks!

Comment: i have taken 4000ms just for example you can take whatever value you want to.

Comment: if you don't want to do background stuff then 200-800 ms will be enough and in case of 0ms i think no splash screen will be shown.

Comment: i just want to replace the black screen that is shown until the app is ready with the splashcreen...

Comment: I dont have any idea about it. You will need to make your application responsive.

Answer (score 0):

In your link to a previous question there is a further link to a [Blog](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.de/2012/04/phonegap-android-splashscreen-just-got.html)

It claims, that with version 1.8.0 of PhoneGap you can call `navigator.splashscreen.hide();`

Check the Blog (read thru all of it as it is a bit missleading on the first two paragraphs).