# I'm getting source code from webview on emulator, but not getting on real device ? - Android

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, android-webview

The code is working on emulator but not working on real device.

```
classJavaScriptInterface{
    private TextView contentView;
    public JavaScriptInterface(TextView aContentView){
        contentView = aContentView;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void processContent(String aContent){
        final String content = aContent;
        contentView.post(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                contentView.setText(content);
                contentView.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
            }
        });
    }
} 

TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.source);
webview1.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(tv2), "INTERFACE");

webview1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){  
    @Override   
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)   
    {   
        view.loadUrl("javascript:window.INTERFACE.processContent(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerText);");        
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, `onPageFinished()` is not always a reliable way to know if the page is truly finished. Depending on what you're loading, there may be additional redirects or frames that will occur *after* `onPageFinished()` is called. See this other SO post for more details: [How to determine when Android WebView is completely done loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587888/how-to-determine-when-android-webview-is-completely-done-loading)

You can quickly check to see if this is the problem by adding a delay in onPageFinished:

```
@Override   
public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, String url)   
{   
    view.postDelayed(new Runnable()   
    {      
        public void run()   
        {
            view.loadUrl("javascript:window.INTERFACE.processContent(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerText);");
        }       
    }, 5000);
}
```

If it works with the delay, you should use the methods described in the other post to fix the issue (don't use postDelayed with a 5s delay in your final product).

Comment: I've tried. But does not work on my real device. I writing Student information system, i must getting data from webview. What would you should me?

Comment: Thank you mikejonesguy. I solved my problem. I learned i need a  @JavascriptInterface, my device android 4.2 and my emulator android 4.0, project running 4.2 or more new android version.