# How could I get MIME type from a web view?

Tags: android, webkit, webview, mime-types, wml

I'm about to develop a browser plugin that detects whether a page is WML and if so, it will be transformed to HTML via an API.

What I want to do is override `onPageFinished` in `WebViewClient` and get MIME type from `WebView`. But there seems no such kind of methods in those two classes.

Am I missing anything or are there some other approaches? Any advice given will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just come up with an idea and seems work.

Load a javascript with `loadUrl` when the page is finish loading (`onProgressChange` to 100%). The js code is like

```
javascript:(function() {
    var wml_root = document.getElementsByTagName('wml');
    if (wml_root && wml_root.length > 0) {
        // apply an XLST or do something here...
    }
})()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [MimeTypeMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.html)'s

`getFileExtensionFromUrl()` followed by `getMimeTypeFromExtension()`

Comment: Thanks, but that won't help if the URL just ends up with `php`, `aspx`, etc. I think I should check the DOM to see DOCTYPE is wml or the root of the XML is `<wml>`.

Comment: How about [guessContentTypeFromStream()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#guessContentTypeFromStream(java.io.InputStream)) you can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134389/access-the-http-response-headers-in-a-webview/3134609#3134609) to get an InputStream

Comment: Thanks for the hint, and I have found a new approach.