# How to handle JavaScript dialog popup in WebView

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-webview, http-status-code-401

I'm trying to figure out how i can handle Javascript pop's in a webview, I have a WebView that is viewing a admin screen of a device on my network. Similar to a router, It has a administration section that then prompts a dialog box with a Username and Pswd field, However in my WebView i get no popup and instead get a 401 Error.

Great example of handling the dialog popup box is in Dolphin browser, they have provided a custom dialog with the two username and password fields.

I believe the below code is what i need to handle the Javascript for the pop up, however i need to create ad username and password dialog that will input the string's that are needed by the webpage.

Any idea's, recommendations, source code, is really appreciated. Thanks,

```
  public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) 
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(Mosembro.this)
                .setTitle("javaScript dialog")
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                        new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() 
                        {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                            {
                                result.confirm();
                            }
                        })
                .setCancelable(false)
                .create()
                .show();

            return true;
        };
```

Comment: I see you got the coding part right here, just confirming did you bind a 'webchrome client' and setJavascriptEnabled(true) on your webview?
because same thing is working at my end.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134389/access-the-http-response-headers-in-a-webview).

Apparently `WebView` can't get the HTTP response.  By creating your own custom `WebViewClient` class, you can 'intercept' the HTTP header and pull the response code.