# In Android, how do I check if the URL being loaded in a webview is an image?

Tags: java, android, url, webview, mime-types

Checking the extension of the file works in most cases, but not for all. Consider the following link:

```
http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTqqcX4SsdwgithvRcjQl_W3Hj-eIc_12FvdeGS2sO31uZ0F1HHqcdRKNo
```

Can I check from the URL if it is a link to an image? If not, is there a way to check after the page has loaded in the webview?

I know that I could download every page using HttpURLConnection, but I'm trying to avoid that approach.

Comment: "Can I check from the URL if it is a link to an image?" -- no. "is there a way to check after the page has loaded in the webview?" -- not that I am aware of. Determining the MIME type of the current content seems to be difficult [even in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1):

Check Response HTTP Header `Content-Type`. It will be one of the `image` types.  For Example, if I open the URL you have provided in Browser, will see `Content-Type` as show below

```
Content-Type:image/jpeg
```

You can use [`HttpHead`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpHead.html) method to fetch just the headers

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, there's no way to obtain HTTP headers in a WebView.

Comment: Sorry, did not know about that.  Will this help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134389/access-the-http-response-headers-in-a-webview  or is that something you already knew and did not want to do

Comment: I had read that one. I was hoping to find a better way, seeing that it has been 5 years since that question. That's a very long time in Android years. :)

Comment: Another option is to use http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpHead.html

Comment: Thanks. Since I'd have to request at least once anyway, the solution to http://stackoverflow.com/a/3134609/1176470 should be the better approach.