# Http Response in Webview Android

Tags: android, webview, httpresponse

I have my activity that loads webview as below

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // set layout
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
    // get loading view
    loadingView = findViewById(R.id.loadingView);
    loadingView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    // extract extras from intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    // get and setup WebView
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    // implement progress bar
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            loadingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // if no title was passed in with the intent use the page's title
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(title)) {
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(view.getTitle());
            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            showErrorAndFinish();
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            // Redirect to deprecated method, so you can use it in all SDK versions
            onReceivedError(view, error.getErrorCode(), error.getDescription().toString(), request.getUrl().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
        }
    });
    // load the url
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

However, I need to look at response of the Url that I load and call to another API URL based on the response.

I have looked so far for this[URL Loading QUestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134389/access-the-http-response-headers-in-a-webview?lq=1) but not much helpful under 5.0. Any suggestions on how should I approach? Should I just use Retrofit in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method?

Also, I cannot modify both the URL's that I am loading .

I would appreciate the response