# Get Response of Xamarin Android WebView Request

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, webview, response

we have implemented a Webview in our Xamarin.Android application with a custom webview client. I can now intercept the ongoing requests with the ShouldInterceptRequest method.

```
public override WebResourceResponse ShouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
    {
        return base.ShouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
    }
```

Now i would like to know if i can get the response of those requests. Is there some function like **ShouldInterceptResponse** ?

**EDIT:** I found this Topic [Access the http response headers in a WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134389/access-the-http-response-headers-in-a-webview) but i hope for a better solution since the post is a few years old..

Comment: The solution you post cant solve this problem?