# WebView works on android 2.3.3, shows blank page on 4.0.1

Tags: android, android-webview

I don't think this is a duplicate, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568063/android-webview-shows-a-blank-page) may be relevant.

As of title: this works perfectly on android 2.3.3, randomly shows a blank page on 4.0.1.
It usually works at first, then start displaying blank pages until the application is
reinstalled.

The code I'm using to display a simple (html only) webpage is a follows:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(final Editable arg0){
    final String result = getResult();
    final String base64 = encode(result);
    //This is the WebView
    results.loadData(base64, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "base64");
}

private String encode(final String value){
    try{
        final byte[] bytes = value.getBytes("UTF-8");
        final String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(bytes,
                              android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
        return base64;
    }
    catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        return "YOULOOZE";
    }
}
```

Comment: any error in your log cat?

Comment: No meaningfull error, no

Comment: you finally solved it? Great! And thanks for the bounty. Maybe you could update your question with the solution

Comment: No, I didn't solve it, but I awarded you the bounty as it would have been lost, and your answer was somewhat helpful. I misflagged your post as an answer, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that your HTML is well formatted. I am not sure of the Doctype it validates against.

This happened to me because I used

```
<script ... />
```

instead of

```
<script ...></script>
```

Any tiny error will make your webview fail silently.

Comment: Is there a way to know wether it is blank because of failed validation or other reasons?

Comment: I can't remember the details, I do recall it being a big headache until I discovered it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that is your solution but can help. Since Android 4.0 WebKit updated into version 534.30. I noticed that on some web pages, after it has completed loading, the WebView redirects its content to a new page that says the following: "Webpage not available The webpage at file:///android_asset/webkit/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address". This is bug of new version of WebKit, in my case javascript from assets folder don't work in offline.